# UITableView rowHeight change on air

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I would like to achieve the same effect as in Reminders (iOS 5). There is a table row height dynamically changing on text view height change.

Imagine I use UITextView in UITableViewCell. I will outstretch this text view in cell, disable scroller and so on... I also will be updating the text view height on its content size height on air. But there is a problem with updating a cell height.

I consider to use `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for appropriate indexPath, but I wonder how to invoke this method. I think of calling `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` but I think, this would reload cell completely and the text in text view would be lost.

Am I missing something or completely wrong? Or should I play with it this way... say caching the cell content and returning it after cell reload? Thank you!

Comment: try calling reloadData method after increasing the row height.  then you load the textview with data

Comment: I think `– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is more efficient. And the problem would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a small [tutorial](http://bit.ly/n6XF2U) on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Well. I did not know `- beginUpdates` and `- endUpdates` do this calls. Is there a worthy writing what is happening between these two methods I should definitely see?

Comment: I haven't found any hint in the Apple documentation what is exactly happening in that block if it is empty – except for the heightForRowAtIndexPath: method call.